# creating XSD using jaxb schemagen

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb2

i am learning JAXb 2.0 and is new to it.

i am trying to generate XSD based on y POJO classes using schemagen and for simple classes it working fine but when my class contains refrence to other classes

schemagen is giving me error below is the error trace for the same

Problem encountered during annotation processing;
see stacktrace below for more information.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.tools.jxc.model.nav.APTNavigator$2.onDeclaredType(APTNavigator.java:436)
        at com.sun.tools.jxc.model.nav.APTNavigator$2.onClassType(APTNavigator.java:410)
        at com.sun.tools.jxc.model.nav.APTNavigator$2.onClassType(APTNavigator.java:464)
        at com.sun.istack.tools.APTTypeVisitor.apply(APTTypeVisitor.java:27)
        at com.sun.tools.jxc.model.nav.APTNavigator.getBaseClass(APTNavigator.java:113)
        at com.sun.tools.jxc.model.nav.APTNavigator.getBaseClass(APTNavigator.java:89)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.PropertyInfoImpl.getIndividualType(PropertyInfoImpl.java:195)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.PropertyInfoImpl.<init>(PropertyInfoImpl.java:137)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.MapPropertyInfoImpl.<init>(MapPropertyInfoImpl.java:71)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.createMapProperty(ClassInfoImpl.java:928)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.addProperty(ClassInfoImpl.java:885)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.findGetterSetterProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:1004)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.getProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:314)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:247)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:213)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:319)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:334)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.j2s.JavaCompilerImpl.bind(JavaCompilerImpl.java:94)
        at com.sun.tools.jxc.apt.SchemaGenerator$1.process(SchemaGenerator.java:119)
        at com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessors$CompositeAnnotationProcessor.process(AnnotationProcessors.java:60)
        at com.sun.tools.apt.comp.Apt.main(Apt.java:454)
        at com.sun.tools.apt.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:258)
        at com.sun.tools.apt.main.Main.compile(Main.java:1102)
        at com.sun.tools.apt.main.Main.compile(Main.java:964)
        at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.processing(Main.java:95)
        at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.process(Main.java:85)
        at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.process(Main.java:67)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.tools.jxc.SchemaGenerator$Runner.main(SchemaGenerator.java:245)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.tools.jxc.SchemaGenerator.run(SchemaGenerator.java:177)
        at com.sun.tools.jxc.SchemaGenerator.run(SchemaGenerator.java:81)
        at com.sun.tools.jxc.SchemaGenerator.main(SchemaGenerator.java:73)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.tools.jxc.SchemaGeneratorFacade.main(SchemaGeneratorFacade.java:60)
C:\Users\Desktop\jaxb\jaxb-ri-20101119\bin\src\com\tr\model\destination\Destination.java:9: package com.tr.model.address does not exist
import com.tr.model.address.BasicAddress;[code]
```

below is the detail of my folder structure

schemagen is located at the following location

```
C:\Users\Desktop\jaxb\jaxb-ri-20101119\bin
```

My Java class based on which i am trying to generate xsd is at the following location

```
C:\Users\Desktop\jaxb\jaxb-ri-20101119\bin\src\com\tr\model\destination
```

Destination.java

while all other classes being refrenced from Destination as well as the class itself are inside the following structure

```
C:\Users\Raisonne\Desktop\jaxb\jaxb-ri-20101119\bin\src\com\raisonne\tr\model
```

i know the problem is with the setting of classpath but i am unable to figure it out ho to set correct classpath for this case

i tried to set system's CLASSPATH variable to the value of

```
C:\Users\Raisonne\Desktop\jaxb\jaxb-ri-20101119\bin\src\com\raisonne\tr\model as well other 2 mentioned in my post but nothing worked out.
```

can any one help me in setting classpath for the schemagen.

thanks in advance

Umesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you have set package declaration of your class to

```
com.tr.model.address
```

where it should be from your dir structure

```
com.tr.model.destination
```

Comment: address is only one error as i have cut down the error trace whatever class i am refreing inide my desination class is being under error/exception

Comment: @umesh , how did you run this schemagen? and are you able to compile all these source ?

Comment: this is what i was trying to do when setting class path using system env variable  schemagen C:\Users\Desktop\jaxb\jaxb-ri-20101119\bin\src\com\tr\model\destination\Destination.java  and yes when there was no refrence to other classes my Destination.java was being complied but in this case no class file is being generated

Comment: I would suggest build up all your classes in one jar file , add that jar file in your classpath , by using env variable or using -classpath switch , then try executing shemagen

Comment: @org.life.java thanks for the helping hands your advise work like a charm